# Как использовать метод WHERE в этом случае?

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня есть переменная типа String,которая называется str. Я хочу сделать выборку из таблицы table все name которые равны str.Я написал так:

```
String sql = "SELECT *FROM table WHERE name=" + str ; 
Cursor cursor = sq.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

Но программа не работает.Пытался использовать LIKE и =?, но все равно. Скажите пожалуйста,где ошибка при выборке?

Comment: `sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='" + str + "';";` так попробуйте

Comment: Вообще вам посоветовали не лучший вариант, потому как таким образом очень легко можно взломать приложения подсунув кавычки в строке. Вы бы указали на каком языке пишите. Во всех языках есть привязываемые параметры. Это когда запрос вида `where name=?` и параметрами в rawQuery или еще в какую нибудь функцию передается требуемое значение

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я думаю так должно заработать

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='"+str+"'"
```

Comment: никогда не подставляйте текст прямо в запрос. используйте подставляемые параметры, например как тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598137/rawqueryquery-selectionargs

Comment: @Mike такой способ работает в c#?

Comment: Сейчас во всех языках драйвера для работы с БД имеют именно такую логику. Вот спросил у гугла "C# database connection". http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program  см. в разделе "Parameterizing the data", чуть сложнее, отдельная функция для установки параметров и по именам вместо позиционных знаков "вопрос".